# NSNumber from AppDelegate won't compare correctly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsnumber

What I've got is a `NSNumber` which is created in the `AppDelegate` and holds a `numberWithBool:TRUE` and a `ViewController` in which a comparison should be made.

My problem is, that the `ViewController` doesn't recognize that my `NSNumber` is set as **1**. The debugger proves that the `NSNumber` is really set as **1** but nothing is happening.

```
if([appDelegate.gotUrl isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithBool:TRUE]])
{
    //will do nothing
}
```

Any solutions for my problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `if (appDelegate.gotUrl.boolValue) {...}` - does that work?

Comment: also note you can use `@YES` instead of `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]`.

Comment: Tried Product -> Clean ? I have tried numerous versions of this code you give and I can't make it fail. Either you are actually comparing a value that isn't set or is false (sets to false by default) or something is wrong which Clean would fix

Comment: Try checking with ...numberWithBool:FALSE] and see if that is triggered, then you know that this property is set to false.  When you set "gotUrl", is that variable a property or local variable ? When you set it, do you use self.gotUrl = TRUE or just "gotUrl = TRUE", there is a difference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if([appDelegate.gotUrl boolValue])
{
    // might do something
}
```